# How do I select portions of an online video to send as an email attachment

Tags: mac

is there any way to take only portions from a video that has been posted online  and send them via email as an attachment?  My son's hockey games are on a video archive and I want to send them out to college coaches but only want the portions that he is playing not the whole game.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to download the video, edit it, and then either upload the edited version to a video hosting site or send the file as an e-mail attachment.

For downloading embedded videos, I use a firefox add-on (DownloadHelper).

Since you're on a Mac, you should have access to iMovie, which will be perfectly adequate for the editing. I don't know what *free* video editing software is available on OSX, but I'm sure they exist.